# Changing MySQL primary key when foreign key contraints exist

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, constraints, mysql-error-1025

I have two already-existing tables which look (in part) roughly like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    old_pk CHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    parent_key CHAR(8),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_key) REFERENCES parent(old_pk)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to add a new auto-incrementing integer `id` column to `parent` and use it as the primary key instead, while still keeping `old_pk` as a unique key and allowing other tables like `child` to reference it in foreign key contraints.  Unfortunately, simply saying `ALTER TABLE parent DROP PRIMARY KEY` doesn't work:

> Error Code : 1025
>
> Error on rename of './data/#sql-4013_70f5e' to './data/parent' (errno: 150)

Some googling suggests that this is due to the existing foreign key reference from `child`.  In essence, I need a way to tell MySQL "use this other column as the primary key, but don't forget the unique-key-ness of the original one".  Is there any way to accomplish this, other than just dropping the key constraints from `child` and reinstating them afterwards?

Assume that I must alter the tables in place, rather than creating copies with the same data and swapping them in later.  I've tried using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` before altering the table, but it does not seem to help.

Comment: that's why i don't make user-visible primary key (i'm all for surrogate primary key from the get-go), user changing requirements are a headache, but it's good to know you're making your database use surrogate primary key http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an index (it could even be UNIQUE) to old_pk before dropping the primary key:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE parent (
    ->     old_pk CHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE child (
    ->     parent_key CHAR(8),
    ->     FOREIGN KEY (parent_key) REFERENCES parent(old_pk)
    ->         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO parent VALUES ('a');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE INDEX old_pk_unique ON parent (old_pk);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE parent DROP PRIMARY KEY;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO child VALUES ('a');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE parent;
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                 |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| parent | CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `old_pk` char(8) NOT NULL,
  KEY `old_pk_unique` (`old_pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO child VALUES ('b');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test/child`, CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_key`) REFERENCES `parent` (`old_pk`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

mysql> INSERT INTO parent VALUES ('b');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO child VALUES ('b');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE parent ADD id INT;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE parent SET id = 1 WHERE old_pk = 'a';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE parent SET id = 2 WHERE old_pk = 'b';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE parent ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE parent;
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                             |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| parent | CREATE TABLE `parent` (
  `old_pk` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `old_pk_unique` (`old_pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -4):

The prevailing opinion in the shops I've worked in has been: Don't use foreign key constraints in your database--enforce unique key and other constraints via TSQL in stored procedures as needed.  It's my experience that in scaled environments check constraints are rarely used.

In the 10 or so years I've been working with relational databases, the only people I know who use check constraints are working on systems that aren't at scale.

Comment: "at [max] scale" practices != best practices.