# How to change primary key of table

Tags: mysql

I want to change primary key of table, initially it was id, now i want to change it to userid

```
   smsusers(id,fname,lname,userid)
```

Here id is varchar type 
adn userid is int type

for this i am trying following query

```
 ALTER TABLE smsusers DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

which is showing this error

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\xrcwrn_sms\#sql-ae0_6f' to 
'.\xrcwrn_sms\smsusers' (errno: 150)
```

`id` of `smsusers` is associated with many tables as foreign key.

How to change the primary key.

Comment: I would like to set the title to "How to change primary key of a MySQL table" but the edit queue is full now

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
ALTER TABLE `database`.`table`   
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`);
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is telling you that you can't drop the primary key yet because it is referenced by one or more foreign keys. You need to identify and drop the foreign keys first, then drop the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

ERROR NO:150 means Foreign key definition problem. I think that some other table has a foreign key constraint depending on this PK, so you need to drop that first and rebuild it later.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191023/changing-mysql-primary-key-when-foreign-key-contraints-exist?rq=1). This is working properly.
  My steps are

```
CREATE INDEX id_pk_unique ON smsusers (id)
ALTER TABLE parent DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE parent ADD PRIMARY KEY (userid);
```