# Change PK in SQL, doesn't work because of FK

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change/update PK of a table in SQL. I use Wampserver.
but this PK is used as foreign to 3 other tables and I can't change it.
Any idea how? Can I disable FK, and then enable them again, and they will have the new PK?
In the table with the PK, there are 5-6 PK, but I want only to change one of them.

```
CREATE TABLE party(
    name varchar(40)  COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL primary key,
    id integer not null,
    foreign key (id) references arxhgos(id)
);
CREATE TABLE boul(
    id integer not null,
    foreign key (id) references person(id),
    part_n varchar(40)  COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
    foreign key (part_n) references party(name),
    date_beg date not null,
    date_end date
);
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191023/changing-mysql-primary-key-when-foreign-key-contraints-exist

Comment: what do you mean? if the PK is duplicate? ofc no.
i mean the table 5-6 different PK, i want to change only 1 of them.but this PK exists as FK to other tables,and to some of them more than one time(since it's a FK)

Comment: I'm referring to a similar question. Have you look at the solution that is provided there? I guessing the problem will have to do with the InnoDB ENGINE. Because you have set a constraint on the relationship between your FK and PK you cannot remove it.

Comment: ah didn't see the link :P will check, it thanks

Comment: Show us the table definition, please.

Comment: You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` to create the table structure.

Comment: @nickD3 are this all the tables? And which primary key do you want to change.

Comment: no i have like 10-12 tables.
i want to change the value of the primary key name in table party(only one row of it not all the values). and it's a foreign key to table boul, and 2 more tables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup what's called Cascading Updates.